# Change Pandas String Column with commas into Float

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I ran the code:

```
df["VotesPerYear"] = df["Votes"]/df["Years"]
```

and received the error:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'float'"
```

df["Votes"] is a string of numbers with commas as thousand separators. What is the best way to convert it into a float so I can perform the operation?

Comment: how did you load this data? if you used `read_csv` then you can tell pandas to treat commas as thousands separators: `read_csv(thousands=',')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to change `,` to nothing and then convert column to float with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) method:

```
df["VotesPerYear"] = df["Votes"].str.replace(",", "").astype(float) / df["Years"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If each element in df['Votes'] is of the form u'x,xxx,xxx.xx' for example, 
we can do:

```
    df["VotesPerYear"] = df["Votes"].map(lambda x: float(''.join(x.split(',')))) / df["Years"]
```