# Pandas: astype error string to float (could not convert string to float: '7,50')

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a dataframe field from string to float in Pandas.

This is the field:

```
In:

print(merged['platnosc_total'].head(100))

Out:

0     0,00
1     4,50
2     0,00
3     0,00
4     0,00
5     4,50
6     6,10
7     7,99
8     4,00
9     7,69
10    7,50
```

Note the 7,50, in the last row, which seems to cause the error:

```
In: 

merged['platnosc_total'].astype(float)

Out:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7,50'
```

Does this mean that the rest got converted, and only the row with 7,50 is the cause?

How can I actually cast this field/column to float?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Pandas String Column with commas into Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462207/change-pandas-string-column-with-commas-into-float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) first:

```
print (merged['platnosc_total'].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float))
0    0.00
1    4.50
2    0.00
3    0.00
4    0.00
5    4.50
6    6.10
7    7.99
8    4.00
Name: platnosc_total, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. I got biased by my Excel, it uses "," for decimal instead of "." - non-English version.

Comment: And if use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) there is no automatic conversion? I am only curious.

Comment: I assume there is, but I was importing from a csv file that stored values with ",". What I meant with bias, was that I assumed that, the coma was appropriate for float, I had some values with a dot "." which I even replaced back to comma, assuming that because my Excel uses coma for floats, I should have "," in there, hence my suprise that there is an error when the text value is in good shape for conversion.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `nan` or empty rows in your column, `astype(float)` won't work.

You should try

```
merged.replace('', np.nan).dropna(subset=['platnosc_total'], inplace=True)
merged['platnosc_total'].astype(float)
```